# Default role after registrating new user

Tags: java, spring, registration, roles

I'm creating a web application using Spring MVC/Security and Hibernate. I've created User and User_Profile tables, plus a joinTable, in the db and mapped them in my application. Whenever a new user registers, I'd like to give him a "ROLE_USER" by default.

I am lost I don't have any idea how to do it ?
And On what layer should I assign him a new role while registering?

```
@Repository("userDao")
```

public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements UserDao {

```
public User findById(int id) {
    return getByKey(id);
}

public User findBySSO(String sso) {
    Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ssoId", sso));
    return (User) crit.uniqueResult();
}

public void saveUser(User user) {
    persist(user);
}
```

}

And this is the part of the controller that contains newUser() :

```
@Controller
```

public class HelloWorldController {

```
@Autowired
UserService service;

//new user
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "registration";
}

//save user
@RequestMapping(value = { "/registration" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(User user, ModelMap model) {
    service.saveUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("user ", user);
    //return "registration";
    return "redirect:/login";
}
...
```

[image: and here's the userDetailsService :]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs to the business layer, as part of creating a new user. How to do it: add the role to the User object, Hibernate will take care of storing it in the DB.

Comment: I don't get it, do you mean I should add a function that combine the role and the user, on the service layer ?

Comment: There should be a service layer function "createUser" and it should do all the necessary default setup.

Comment: I have a service layer, but it doesn't contain the fucntion 'createUser'. This function is in the dao layer. should I move to the service layer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AuthenticatedUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7995477185057372770L;
private final int id;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticatedUser.class);
public AuthenticatedUser(Person person) {
    super(person.getEmail(), person.getPassword(), getAuthoritiesFromUser(person));
    this.id = person.getId();
    this.firstname= person.getName();
    this.lastname = person.getSurname();

}

public static List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthoritiesFromUser(Person person) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    if("aktifUser".equals(person.getRole().getName())){
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_NORMALUSER"));
    }

    if("adminUser".equals(person.getRole().getName())){
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_COMPANY"));
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_NORMALUSER"));
    }

    if("employeeUser".equals(person.getRole().getName())){
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));          
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_COMPANY"));
    }

    logger.info("Granted Auths" + grantedAuths.toString() );
    return grantedAuths;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?